# Intel DTCP Sample Implementation kit (SIK) contents

Tags: drm, dlna

I have some queries regarding Intel SIK.

Does this SIK contains the complete implementation of DTCP stack ? ie: including the implementation for Elliptic Curve Cryptography (ECC) used by DTCP.? Can you please explain what all modules will be available as part of this SIK.?

Basically,We have to develop DTCP stack for an arm platform. By using SIK, what all will be available and what modules are to be developed by us.?

Comment: DTCP is a licensed technology where many details are secrets and only available to members of DTLA http://www.dtcp.com/ , so you're not going to have public comment on this. For the record, DTCP-IP SIK can be requested at http://www.dtcpsik.com/ but you need to be a member of DTLA to get access to it.

Comment: The very same question was posted on Intel web site: http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/355999